# DateTime.TryParse works as different cultures even when set

Tags: c#, .net

So my string `dateRangeStart` goes in the format `2019-01-31` i.e. 31st Jan 2019

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-UK", true);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateRangeStart))
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    if(DateTime.TryParse(dateRangeStart, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    {
        /// whatever
    }
}
```

Using the same routine, if I put in `31-01-2019` - it fails to parse. Why? I've told it that it's a UK date? Can it not recognise `dd-MM-yyyy` formats?! but totally ok with `MM-dd-yyyy`?

Also happens if I swap `culture` for `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: It's `en-GB` rather than `en-UK` methinks.

Comment: You're right, but even with it swapped to invariant it still fails?

Comment: @jamheadart wouldn't invariant be essentially US? So `31-01-2019` would not be a valid date, it should be `01-31-2019`.

Comment: Hmm ok, but then it manages to work it out if I put in `2019-01-31` - anyway yeah `en-GB` has fixed it

Comment: This has raised an interesting if somewhat unrelated question: (1) Clearly `CultureInfo()` accepts `en-UK` as a locale (since it doesn't throw), and (2) But it doesn't give the correct date format for the UK. I wonder what gives...

Comment: Hmm so it seems that if it doesn't understand the bit after the hypen, it just uses the first part - in this case `en`, which seems to result in it using the US date format.

Comment: I forgot to mention: `DateTime.TryParse()` will happily parse `yyyy-MM-dd` format date strings, even if you're using the `en-GB` (or another) locale, because it recognises the ISO date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__), use [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__). This way, you have full control over the string representation format you're attempting to parse:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateRangeStart))
{
    DateTime d;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateRangeStart, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    {
        /// whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, although my input can be varied I'd have to check for certain formats before parsing exactly.

Comment: There's another overload that takes in a `string[]` for multiple possible formats.